# Issues with overlapping elements in layout (css, html)

Tags: html, css

I have some strange things going on with my layout that I believe is css-related.

I have a main div, toolbar div, and an dojo expandopane (that starts closed). The top of the main div overlaps the toolbar div until the expando pane is expanded once. After this is done, everything looks okay. On top of that the scale_bar is not integrated into the toolContainer.

Here is the html body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>A Company | SIG WEB</title>

  <script>
  var dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: false,
    async: true,
    packages: [
      {
        name: "agsjs",
        "location": '/SPE_SIG/agsjs' // for xdomain load
      }, {
        name: "js",
        "location": '/test/js'
      }]
    };
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/widget_styles.css">

    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/"></script>


    <script src="js/Map.js"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojox.layout.ExpandoPane");
  </script>-->

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
  })
  </script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div class = "contentclass" id="content" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">

    <div id="rightPane" data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ExpandoPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right',title:'Outils',startExpanded:false">

      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
        <!-- <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-dojo-props="title:'LÃ©gende', selected:true">
          <div id="legendDiv"></div>
        </div> -->
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-dojo-props="title:'LÃ©gende', selected:true">
          <div id="layerListDom"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Impressions'">

          <select name="printLayout" id="printLayoutId" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
            <option value="A0_paysage">A0 Paysage</option>
            <option value="A0_portrait">A0 Portrait</option>
            <option value="A1_paysage">A1 Paysage</option>
            <option value="A1_portrait">A1 Portrait</option>
            <option value="A2_paysage">A2 Paysage</option>
            <option value="A2_portrait">A2 Portrait</option>
            <option value="A3_paysage">A3 Paysage</option>
            <option value="A3_portrait">A3 Portrait</option>
            <option value="A4_paysage" selected="selected">A4 Paysage</option>
            <option value="A4_portrait">A4 Portrait</option>
            <!-- <option value="Letter ANSI A Landscape" selected>Letter ANSI A Landscape</option>
            <option value="Letter ANSI A Portrait">Letter ANSI A Portrait</option>
            <option value="Tabloid ANSI B Landscape">Tabloid ANSI B Landscape</option>
            <option value="Tabloid ANSI B Portrait">Tabloid ANSI B Portrait</option> -->
          </select>
          <br>
          <select id="format" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
            <OPTION value="PDF">PDF</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="PNG32">PNG</OPTION>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <!-- <input type="checkbox" id="check_scales" checked
          data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox"
          data-dojo-props="checked: true"> -->
          <div id="scale_check"></div>
          <label for="scale_check">Imprimer Ã  l'Ã©chelle</label>

          <div id="scale_select" class="comboClass"></div>

          <button id="print_button_bis" type="button"></button>
          <p id="print_status"></p>
          <a target="_blank" id="output_url" href="#"></a>
          <!--<input type="button" id="print" value = "Print" onclick="printMap();"/>-->


        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="identifyPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Identification'">
          <select id="id_select" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
            <OPTION value="Aucune identifiÃ©e">EntitÃ©s identifiÃ©es</OPTION>
          </select>

        </div>


        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="measurePane" data-dojo-props="title:'Mesure'">
          <!-- <div id="measure_check"></div>
          <label for="scale_check">Activer les outils de mensuration</label> -->

          <div id="measurementDiv"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="toolContainer">
      <div class="navBarClass" id="navToolbar" data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar" data-dojo-props="region:'top'" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
        <button type="button" id="zoomin"></button>
        <button type="button" id="zoomout"></button>
        <button type="button" id="zoomfullext"></button>
        <button type="button" id="zoomprev"></button>
        <button type="button" id="zoomnext"></button>
        <button type="button" id="pan"></button>
        <button type="button" id="id_button"></button>
        <!-- <button type="button" id="deactivate"></button> -->
      </div>
      <div class="scaleBarClass" id="scale_bar"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="overflow: hidden;width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">


        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="LOGO" id="logo"/></a>

        <a href="mailto:me@gmail.com" id="space">US 2017</a>


      <div id="search"></div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index:0;
  position: relative;
}
#search {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 20px;
  left: 75px;
}


#rightPane {
  width: 20%;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  left:20px;
  z-index:100;
  width:75px;
}

#logo-div{
 z-index:3;
}

#space {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  left:20px;
  z-index:3;
  width:75px;
  font-size:9px;
}

#legendPane {
  border: solid #97DCF2 1px;
}


h3 {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}



.comboClass{
  width: 50px;
}

.zoominIcon {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/30);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

.zoomoutIcon {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/30);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

.zoomfullextIcon {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/30);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

.zoomprevIcon {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/30);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

.zoomnextIcon {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/30);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

.panIcon {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/30);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

.deactivateIcon {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/30);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}

.identifyIcon {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/30/30);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 5px;
}


.contentclass {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.toolContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navBarClass {

  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.scaleBarClass {

  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 15px 115px;
}
```

I have a stripped down version of the app on a public facing url [here](http://arcgis.polynesienne-des-eaux.pf/test/).
This is how the page loads (notice the little overlap of the map over the toolbar):
[image: before expand]

This is how it looks after expanding the 'expandopane'--the elements fit as expected:
[image: after expand]

Comment: Please add a fiddle :)

Comment: @DierigPatrick I put it in a codepen for now--will work on jsfiddle but I was having issues with a few things initially.

Comment: @DierigPatrick The url is public facing now, if you are interested in taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.claro .dijitToolbar {
min-height:40px;}
```

Should fix the issue :)

Comment: Can the person who -1 explain why and/or give an alternative solution?